# Use distinct method with order on a many to many relation with ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-order-by, distinct

I have a classic many to many relationship defined like this in ActiveRecord:

```
class Developer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :developers_code_reviews
  has_many :code_reviews, through: :developers_code_reviews
end

class DevelopersCodeReview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :code_review
  belongs_to :developer
end

class CodeReview < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :developers_code_reviews
  has_many :developers, through: :developers_code_reviews
end
```

and I basically want to have a `Developer` array sorted by `code_review.created_at` without doubles.

My first attempt was the basic one: `Developer.order('code_reviews.created_at': :asc)` which triggers this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'code_reviews.created' in 'order clause`.

After a few googling I understood the join was not automatically performed by ActiveRecord so I added it: `Developer.joins(:code_reviews).order('code_reviews.created_at': :asc)`. This one works but has doubles inside. I need to have a developer to appear only once in this array.

If I try to create a distinct on that query, ActiveRecord/MySQL complains that the `ORDER BY` is not performed on a column that is in the SELECT. How can I solve this problem?

I googled it quite a lot I can't find anything.

**NOTE**

The MYSQL query which works but *with* doubles looks like this:

```
SELECT `developers`.*
FROM `developers`
INNER JOIN `developers_code_reviews` ON `developers_code_reviews`.`developer_id` = `developers`.`id`
INNER JOIN `code_reviews` ON `code_reviews`.`id` = `developers_code_reviews`.`code_review_id` 
ORDER BY `code_reviews`.`created_at` ASC
```

and I'd like to have a distinct on the developers.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer thanks to this clear example on MySQL sub queries: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/

With this example, I understood that I needed a sub query looking like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM developers
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT developer_id, max(updated_at) max_updated_at
  FROM developers_code_reviews
  GROUP BY developer_id
) dcr
ON developers.id = dcr.developer_id
ORDER BY maxupdt
```

Translated to ruby in my case:

```rb
class DevelopersCodeReview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :code_review
  belongs_to :developer

  class << self
    def developer_queue
      select('developer_id, max(updated_at) max_updated_at').
      group(:developer_id)
    end
  end
end

class Developer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :slack_workspace
  belongs_to :project, optional: true

  class << self
    def queue
      developer_queue = DevelopersCodeReview.developer_queue.to_sql

      joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (#{developer_queue}) dcr ON id = dcr.developer_id").
      order(max_updated_at: :asc)
    end
  end
end
```